# using OpenACC ,error information displays :[if not already present]

Tags: c++, openacc

When I compiled the code with OpenACC,I got the error information:[if not already present]

```
#include<iostream>

#include<openacc.h>

using namespace std;


int main(){
int i,j,sum=0;
#pragma acc parallel loop copyin(i,j) copyout(sum)
for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
           #pragma acc loop
    for(int j=0;j<200;j++){
           sum=i+j;
    }

  }
  cout<<sum<<endl;
}
```

Result shows:

> main:
>
> ```
>  8, Generating copyin(i) [if not already present]
>     Generating copyout(sum) [if not already present]
>     Generating copyin(j) [if not already present]
>     Generating NVIDIA GPU code
>    10, #pragma acc loop gang, vector(96) /* blockIdx.x >threadIdx.x */
>     12, #pragma acc loop seq
> 13, Accelerator restriction: induction variable live-out from loop: sum
> ```

I don't quite understand why the error shows induction variable live-out from loop: sum.

Answer (score 2):

"live-out" means that a global device scalar variable is being assigned in the device kernel and then being used on the host.  It inhibits auto-parallelization since it creates a dependency.  Though since you've forced parallelization, consider it a warning that the code will likely result in a wrong answer.

The order in which a parallel loop executes the iterations is non-deterministic. Hence which ever thread happens to update 'sum' last, will be the result.  To get the last value, the loops iterations would need to be run sequentially, hence the dependency.